# How to reference from external subprojects in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a sample project, with the following setup:

- Root Project A

  - Sub Project 1
  - Sub Project 2
- Root Project B

  - Sub Project 1
  - Sub Project 2

I add following code in sub project A-1's settings.gradle to reference from sub project B-1:

```
include ':RootProjectB:SubProject1'
project(':RootProjectB:SubProject1').projectDir = new File('/Users/RootProjectB/SubProject1')
```

but sub project B-1 need root project B's config, and get compile error.
so, how to reference from sub project B-1?

Comment: If your projects are for Java, you can try composite builds https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html by using dependency substitution.